# Role-based navigation sidebar in ReactJS using PrivateRoute.js

Tags: reactjs

I am new to ReactJS and I am trying to modify my `PrivateRoute.js` to be role based. The current PrivateRoute only checks if a user is existing but I am not sure how to change it to a role-based

The sidebar navigation consists of the ff:

- Dashboard
- Accounts
- Assets
- Accesses
- Access Scanner
- Scan Scheduler
- Scan Logs

The permissions are the ff:

- **Admin**: Can access everything
- **Dashboard_User**: Can only access the Dashboard and should only see the Dashboard in the sidebar
- **Report_User***: Can only access Accounts, Assets, and Accesses and should only see the three in the sidebar

Here are the related files:

`PrivateRoute.js`

```
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../Context/AuthContext'


const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
    let {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
    return(
        <Route {...rest}>{!user ? <Redirect to="/login/login-page" /> :   children}</Route>
    )
}

export default PrivateRoute;
```

`AuthContext.js`

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const AuthContext = createContext()

export default AuthContext;


export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

    let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [user, setUser] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [group, setGroup] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const history = useHistory()

    let loginUser = async (e )=> {
        e.preventDefault()
        let response = await fetch('authentication/api/token/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'username':e.target.username.value, 'password':e.target.password.value})
        })
        let data = await response.json()

        console.log('data:', data)
        console.log('response:', response)

        if(response.status === 200){
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            setGroup(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            history.push('/dashboards/index')
        }else{
            alert('Invalid username or password!')
        }
    }

    let logoutUser = () => {
        setAuthTokens(null)
        setUser(null)
        localStorage.removeItem('authTokens')
        history.push('/login/login-page')
    }


    let updateToken = async ()=> {

        let response = await fetch('api/token/refresh/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'refresh':authTokens?.refresh})
        })

        let data = await response.json()
        
        if (response.status === 200){
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
        }else{
            logoutUser()
        }

        if(loading){
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }

    let contextData = {
        user:user,
        group:group,
        authTokens:authTokens,
        loginUser:loginUser,
        logoutUser:logoutUser,
    }


    useEffect(()=> {

        if(loading){
            updateToken()
        }

        let fourMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 4

        let interval =  setInterval(()=> {
            if(authTokens){
                updateToken()
            }
        }, fourMinutes)
        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)

    }, [authTokens, loading])

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData} >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

`AppMain/index.js`

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Suspense, lazy, Fragment, useState } from "react";

import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import PrivateRoute from '../../Login/Utils/PrivateRoute'
import { AuthProvider } from '../../Login/Context/AuthContext'

const Dashboards = lazy(() => import("../../Dashboard/index"));
const AccountList = lazy(() => import("../../Account/Pages/AccountList"));
const AssetList = lazy(() => import("../../Asset/Pages/AssetList"))
const AccessScanners = lazy(() => import("../../Scanner/Pages/AccessScanner"));
const ScanScheduler = lazy(() => import("../../Scanner/Pages/ScanScheduler"));
const ScanLogsNav = lazy(() => import("../../Scanner/Pages/ScanLogs"));
const AccessList = lazy(() => import ("../../Access/Pages/AccessList"))
const LoginPage = lazy(() => import ("../../Login/Pages/LoginPage"))



const AppMain = () => {

  return (
    
    <Fragment>
      {/* Login */}
      <AuthProvider>
      
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div className="loader-container">
              <div className="loader-container-inner">
                <h6 className="mt-5">
                  Please wait while we load all the Components
                  <small>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                  </small>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <Route path="/login/login-page" component={LoginPage} />
        </Suspense>
      
        
      {/* Access */}
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div className="loader-container">
              <div className="loader-container-inner">
                <h6 className="mt-5">
                  Please wait while we load all the Components
                  <small>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                  </small>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <PrivateRoute path="/access/access-list" component={AccessList} />
        </Suspense>

        {/* Account */}
            <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="loader-container">
            <div className="loader-container-inner">
              <h6 className="mt-5">
                Please wait while we load all the Components
                <small>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                </small>
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <PrivateRoute path="/account/account-list" component={AccountList} />
      </Suspense>

      {/* Asset */}
        <Suspense
          fallback={
            <div className="loader-container">
              <div className="loader-container-inner">
                <h6 className="mt-5">
                  Please wait while we load all the Components
                  <small>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                  </small>
                </h6>
              </div>
            </div>
          }
        >
          <PrivateRoute path="/asset/asset-list" component={AssetList} />
        </Suspense>

      {/* Scanner */}
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="loader-container">
            <div className="loader-container-inner">
              <h6 className="mt-5">
                Please wait while we load all the Components
                <small>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                </small>
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <PrivateRoute path="/scanner/access-scanners" component={AccessScanners} />
      </Suspense>

      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="loader-container">
            <div className="loader-container-inner">
              <h6 className="mt-5">
                Please wait while we load all the Components
                <small>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                </small>
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <PrivateRoute path="/scanner/scan-scheduler" component={ScanScheduler} />
      </Suspense>

      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="loader-container">
            <div className="loader-container-inner">
              <h6 className="mt-5">
                Please wait while we load all the Components
                <small>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                </small>
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <PrivateRoute path="/scanner/scan-logs" component={ScanLogsNav} />
      </Suspense>

      {/* Dashboards */}
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="loader-container">
            <div className="loader-container-inner">
              <h6 className="mt-3">
                Please wait while we load the Dashboard
                <small>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam
                </small>
              </h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        }
      >
        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboards" component={Dashboards} />
      </Suspense>

      <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login/login-page" />} />
      {/* <Route path="*"><div>404:Page Not Found!</div></Route> */}
      </AuthProvider>
      <ToastContainer />
    </Fragment>
  );
  
};

export default AppMain;
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the relevant files that satisfy the conditions I am looking for

`PrivateRoute.js`

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useContext } from 'react'
import AuthContext from '../Context/AuthContext'

const PrivateRoute = ({ children, roles, ...rest }) => {

    let {user} = useContext(AuthContext)
    const isAllowed = roles?.includes(user?.group)

    return(
        <Route {...rest}>{!isAllowed ? null :   children}</Route>
    )

};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

`AuthContext.js`

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const AuthContext = createContext()

export default AuthContext;


export const AuthProvider = ({children}) => {

    let [authTokens, setAuthTokens] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [user, setUser] = useState(()=> localStorage.getItem('authTokens') ? jwt_decode(localStorage.getItem('authTokens')) : null)
    let [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

    const history = useHistory()

    let loginUser = async (e )=> {

        e.preventDefault()
        let response = await fetch('authentication/api/token/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'username':e.target.username.value, 'password':e.target.password.value})
        })
        let data = await response.json()

        if(response.status === 200){
            
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            localStorage.setItem('userGroup', user.group)
            if (user.group === 'HADES_DEV_Administrators' || user.group === 'HADES_DEV_Dashboard_Users') {
                history.push('/dashboards/index')
            } else {
                history.push('/account/account-list')
            }

        }else{
            alert('Invalid username or password!')
        }
    }

    let logoutUser = () => {
        setAuthTokens(null)
        setUser(null)
        localStorage.removeItem('authTokens')
        localStorage.removeItem('userGroup')
        history.push('/login/login-page')
    }

    let updateToken = async ()=> {

        let response = await fetch('authentication/api/token/refresh/', {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'refresh':authTokens?.refresh})
        })

        let data = await response.json()
        
        if (response.status === 200){
            setAuthTokens(data)
            setUser(jwt_decode(data.access))
            localStorage.setItem('authTokens', JSON.stringify(data))
            // localStorage.setItem('userGroup', user.group)
        }else{
            logoutUser()
        }

        if(loading){
            setLoading(false)
        }
    }


    let contextData = {
        user:user,
        // group:group,
        authTokens:authTokens,
        loginUser:loginUser,
        logoutUser:logoutUser,
    }


    useEffect(()=> {

        if(loading){
            updateToken()
        }

        let fourMinutes = 1000 * 60 * 4

        let interval =  setInterval(()=> {
            if(authTokens){
                updateToken()
            }
        }, fourMinutes)
        return ()=> clearInterval(interval)

    }, [authTokens, loading])

    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider value={contextData} >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

`AppMain/index.js`

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Suspense, lazy, Fragment, useContext } from "react";
import { Spinner } from "reactstrap";

import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";

import PrivateRoute from '../../Login/Utils/PrivateRoute'
import { AuthProvider } from '../../Login/Context/AuthContext'
import AuthContext from '../../Login/Context/AuthContext'

const Dashboards = lazy(() => import("../../Dashboard/index"));
const AccountList = lazy(() => import("../../Account/Pages/AccountList"));
const AssetList = lazy(() => import("../../Asset/Pages/AssetList"))
const AccessScanners = lazy(() => import("../../Scanner/Pages/AccessScanner"));
const ScanScheduler = lazy(() => import("../../Scanner/Pages/ScanScheduler"));
const ScanLogsNav = lazy(() => import("../../Scanner/Pages/ScanLogs"));
const AccessList = lazy(() => import ("../../Access/Pages/AccessList"))
const LoginPage = lazy(() => import ("../../Login/Pages/LoginPage"))



const AppMain = () => {

  const gapReportRequiredRoles = ['Admin',
                                  'Report_User',]
  const adminRequiredRoles = ['Admin']
  const dashboardRequiredRoles = ['Admin', 
                                  'Dashboard_Users']

  const showLoading = () => {
    return(
      <div className="loader-container">
        <Spinner style={{width: "5rem",height: "5rem"}} color="primary"/>
      </div>
    )
  }

  return (

    <Fragment>
      {/* Login */}
      <AuthProvider>
      
        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
          <Route path="/login/login-page" component={LoginPage} />
        </Suspense>
      
        
        {/* Access */}
        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
          {/* <PrivateRoute path="/access/access-list" component={AccessList} /> */}
          <PrivateRoute roles={gapReportRequiredRoles}>
          <Route path="/access/access-list" component={AccessList} />
        </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        {/* Account */}
        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
        {/* <PrivateRoute path="/account/account-list" component={AccountList} />
         */}
         <PrivateRoute roles={gapReportRequiredRoles}>
            <Route path="/account/account-list" component={AccountList} />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        {/* Asset */}
        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
          {/* <PrivateRoute path="/asset/asset-list" component={AssetList} />
           */}
           <PrivateRoute roles={gapReportRequiredRoles}>
          <Route path="/asset/asset-list" component={AssetList} />
        </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        {/* Scanner */}
        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
          {/* <PrivateRoute path="/scanner/access-scanners" component={AccessScanners} /> */}
          <PrivateRoute roles={adminRequiredRoles}>
            <Route path="/scanner/access-scanners" component={AccessScanners} />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
        {/* <PrivateRoute path="/scanner/scan-scheduler" component={ScanScheduler} />
         */}
          <PrivateRoute roles={adminRequiredRoles}>
            <Route path="/scanner/scan-scheduler" component={ScanScheduler} />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
          {/* <PrivateRoute path="/scanner/scan-logs" component={ScanLogsNav} />
          */}
          <PrivateRoute roles={adminRequiredRoles}>
            <Route path="/scanner/scan-logs" component={ScanLogsNav} />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        {/* Dashboards */}
        <Suspense fallback={showLoading()}>
          {/* <PrivateRoute path="/dashboards" component={Dashboards} /> */}
          {/* <PrivateRoute roles ={['HADES_DEV_Administrators', 'HADES_DEV_Dashboard_Users']}>
            <Dashboards />
          </PrivateRoute> */}
          <PrivateRoute roles={dashboardRequiredRoles}>
            <Route path="/dashboards" component={Dashboards} />
          </PrivateRoute>
        </Suspense>

        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/login/login-page" />} />
        {/* <Route path="*"><div>404:Page Not Found!</div></Route> */}
        </AuthProvider>
        <ToastContainer />
      </Fragment>
    );
  
};

export default AppMain;
```